How do I get .isDisplayed() to work in an if/else statement?
I'm building out an automation test with Selenium and when I attempt to use an if/else statement with .isDisplayed I will always get this response. "no such element: Unable to locate element:" The webelement it is checking for is not displayed which should direct it to complete the else statement, but it ends the test. How would I write a work around?
@Step("Click the Open IRA Account")
public PortfolioHomePage clickOpenIRAAccount(){
     waitForElementToAppear(signOutBtn);
     if (openAccountBtn.isDisplayed()) {
         waitForElementToAppear(openAccountBtn);
         openAccountBtn.click();
     } else {
         waitForElementToAppear(finishMyApplicationButton);
         finishMyApplicationButton.click();
     }
    return this;
}

I have tried {}Catch(Exceptions e) but that didn't help.

The intent of .isDisplayed() is to check if an already found/existing element is in fact visible/displayed or not. What you are describing is that the element is not found. To account for this, you need to first check if the element exists and then if it's visible. If it doesn't exist, then you can consider it not visible.
The way to determine if an element exists without throwing an exception is to use the pattern
List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(...);
if (e.isEmpty())        {
    // element does not exist
} else {
    // element does exist
}

We can incorporate this into your method
@Step("Click the Open IRA Account")
public PortfolioHomePage clickOpenIRAAccount(){
    waitForElementToAppear(signOutBtn);
    List<WebElement> openAccountBtn = driver.findElements(...);
    if (!openAccountBtn.isEmpty() && openAccountBtn.get(0).isDisplayed()) {
        openAccountBtn.get(0).click();
    } else {
        waitForElementToAppear(finishMyApplicationButton);
        finishMyApplicationButton.click();
    }
    return this;
}


Some feedback...

You have a logic error in your current method
if (openAccountBtn.isDisplayed()) {
     waitForElementToAppear(openAccountBtn);

You check to see if openAccountBtn is displayed, it passes, and then you wait for it to appear ??? using waitForElementToAppear(openAccountBtn). If it's already visible, and it is if that if condition passes, then there's no point in waiting for it to be visible. I removed that wait call from my code.

Your method name is clickOpenIRAAccount() but if the if condition fails, you click the finishMyApplicationButton. I don't know your scenario but that doesn't seem like it belongs in a method called clickOpenIRAAccount(). I would suggest that if the openAccountBtn doesn't exist, then that method should throw an exception. Otherwise, when you exit that method you are in an inconsistent state in your test.



Hi JeffC, Thank you for the answer! I added your adjustments to my method and the test was successful.
